Disable scrollbar one sheet in excel by vba
I want to disable h/v scrollbar in a just one sheet. When I try to vba code or options all pages effects but I want to run the rule just one sheet.
what is the solution?
Thanx.
I tried options checkbox. All pages effected but must be just one sheet.

What is your code snippet that you tried?

there is no code snippet.

You said you tried vba code

ouw sorry, I've tried found on internet samples.


Using Workbook_SheetActivate event code to switch the setting

Microsoft documentation:

Workbook.SheetActivate event (Excel)

' Insert the code into ThisWorkbook module

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Const SHT_NAME = "Sheet1"
    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = (Not Sh.Name = SHT_NAME)
        .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = (Not Sh.Name = SHT_NAME)
    End With
End Sub



It does not work. no changed anything.

How do you insert the code in your file? I've loaded the image in my answer.

Thank you bro, that's work. But This way you can control scrolling with mouse the sheet. I want to just buzzed screen like when you deleted rows on google sheets.
